# Finding the components of a vectors in a cube

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, physics

The question states; In the figure below, vector b and c are intersecting faces of a cube of edge a. Find teh components of vector d, where d = the scalar product of vectors b and c. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcxTb.jpg)

With reference to the imagine above. I fist began by describing vectors.
        Vector b= ai+aj-bk 
  The (a) came from the lenght of the cube. The (-b) from the fact that the vectr has a component in the negative direction z-plane. That is not equal to the lenght of once edge.

```
                              Vector c= -di+aj+ak
```

Vector c was identified with the same assuption as that of B

I used the vectors components to find the scalar product that i found to be;
     bxc = (a^2-ab)-(a^2+bc)+(a^2-ac)

My classmates and I have argued over the questions, and require verification on the method and the answer itself.

Comment: Vector $b$ lies in the $xy$ plane, in the back face of the cube. Its z-component is zero. For all three vectors in this problem, each component is either 0 or $a$ (times a unit base vector).

Comment: “Find teh [sic] components of the vector d, where d = the scalar product of vectors b and c.” Is d a vector or a scalar? It can’t be both.